MongoDB gives bad auth 8000 error when connecting from google app engine, but works on localhost
I created a simple backend in NodeJS and Mongoose, and it works perfectly on localhost, but I deployed it to Google App Engine, and it gives this:
2024-08-01 16:02:57 default[20240731t153246]  Error: {
2024-08-01 16:02:57 default[20240731t153246]    "errorResponse": {
2024-08-01 16:02:57 default[20240731t153246]      "ok": 0,
2024-08-01 16:02:57 default[20240731t153246]      "errmsg": "bad auth : authentication failed",
2024-08-01 16:02:57 default[20240731t153246]      "code": 8000,
2024-08-01 16:02:57 default[20240731t153246]      "codeName": "AtlasError"
2024-08-01 16:02:57 default[20240731t153246]    },
2024-08-01 16:02:57 default[20240731t153246]    "ok": 0,
2024-08-01 16:02:57 default[20240731t153246]    "code": 8000,
2024-08-01 16:02:57 default[20240731t153246]    "codeName": "AtlasError",
2024-08-01 16:02:57 default[20240731t153246]    "connectionGeneration": 0
2024-08-01 16:02:57 default[20240731t153246]  }.

this is my code:
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const password = encodeURIComponent('myStrongPassword');
module.exports = async (e) => {
  console.log('Attempting DB Connection');
  mongoose
    .connect(
      'mongodb+srv://myUserName:'+password+'@MyDBName.to4ptev.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=MyAppName',
      {}
    )
    .then((result) => {
      console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    });
};

I allowed all IP addresses to connect to it, and it stil will not work on app engine. I verified the URI is correct.

Maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

How did you create the user? On Atlas you do it differently than on locally installed MongoDB.

whoops i forgot to add that i am using Atlas

i created the user when i created the project or database or whatever. though the users password has been changed multiple times. i cannot remember too well since i created the database a long time ago
